# current path didn't match in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am a beginner for django. I tried to make my 1st project helloworld, with the help of tutorials I installed and followed their instructions. When I run my project in server it shows an error 404, the current path didn't match any of these.

myproj/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from helworld.views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', hello),
]
```

helworld/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse(request, "hello world!")
```

This is my code when I run it.
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/helworld
Using the URLconf defined in myproj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
index/
The current path, helworld, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

I searched for solution but being a beginner its bit tough for me to solve this error. so kindly help me with an easy clarification.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to get the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/helworld` but you don't have such a url pattern. Try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/` instead

Comment: I tried the http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/ url though it showing an empty page I don't know what mistake I have made. kindly, anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In your route you define the path related to the **hello view** to "/index/" as such you should search **http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/** and not **http://127.0.0.1:8000/helworld**

If you want to access the page with the **hellword** do the following :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hellword', hello),
]
```

[Django Path Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#path)